# Node.js Sqlite3 if row exists

Tags: javascript, node.js, sqlite

Is there any way to check if a row exists using node.js and the sqlite module. This function is the best i have now, but it always returns false between the module is asynchronous

```
function auth(uname, pwd) {
    var userExists = false;
    authDB.serialize(function() {
        authDB.each("SELECT * FROM Users WHERE username = '" + uname + "' AND password = '" + pwd + "' LIMIT 1)", function(err, row) {
            userExists = true;
            console.log(userExists)
        });
    });
    return userExists;
}
```

Is there any way to do this?

Thanks

Comment: What should happen if the row exists?

Comment: The value user Exists should change to true. In any respect, i simply want to return true if the row exists

Comment: Its an asynchronous call, it is not possible

Answer (score 1):

Check the value of `row`, that is the result of your query. Depending on your database driver you will get `[]` or `null` in case the row did not exist.

I never used `sqlite3` in node, but you can easily check what is the value, by simply searching for a row that for sure does not exist.

And BTW you should return the `userExists` from inside the callback:

```
 function(err, row) {
        if (row != ...
             return true;
        userExists = true;
        console.log(userExists)
    });
```

because the database query is asynchronous. But in your code you're returning `userExists` from outside the callback that will always occur earlier than your database query finishes.

Comment: I think `DB.each` is not executed when no row is returned, so it is impossible to check the row variable.